# What are the advantages of an AP Ezreal over an AD Ezreal in mid lane?

Tags: league-of-legends

In the past when I played LoL, I generally see Ezreals building mostly attack damage and fill the role of the team's ranged AD carry.

I've recently started seeing Ezreal going mid lane and build AP to fill the role of the team's AP carry.

What are the advantages of building AP rather than AD on Ezreal? Doesn't only 2 of his spells scale of AP?

Answer (score 8):

Ezreal is one of those champions that can be built several ways. As pure AD, as an AP caster, or as a hybrid.

All of Ezreal's skills scale off of AP. Essense Flux(0.7 AP ratio) and  Archane Shift(0.75 AP ratio) both scale solely on ability power ratios while his Mystic Shot(1.0 AD ratio + 0.2 AP ratio) and Trueshot Barrage(1.0 AD ratio and 0.9 AP ratio) scale off of both AD and AP ratios.

**Advantages include:**

- AP Ezreal will have higher burst damage. This will allow Ezreal to play a more Guerilla play style where he comes in, harasses with his skills and then back off. He does not need to stay in range for his auto-attack which is the main source of damage for any AD carry.
- His Mystic Shot can proc on-hit effects so building a Lichbane will hit like a truck. this again leads to *very* strong harass.
- His ultimate Trueshot Barrage is a global ultimate and can deal A LOT of damage if it hits. An AP Ezreal's Trueshot Barrage will be much stronger than an AD Ezreals since AP it is cheaper to build than AD.

**Disadvantages include:**

- Less sustained damage because AP Ezreals will be limited by their cooldown and mana.
- Much more dependant on the Summoner's ability to use skill shots because *every* single one of Ezreal's skill is a skill shot. Missing these skill shots essentially means you can't deal any damage.
- Unable to utilize Ezreal's passive Rising Spell Force and Essence Flux's attack speed boost very well. An AP Ezreal's attack damage would be too low to benefit from attack speed much.
- Unable to utilize Mystic Shot's on-hit effect fully. With the exception of Sheen or Lichbane, an AP Ezreal will not be building any items that will proc effects while attacking (Mystic Shot counts as physical attack). So life steal or slow benefits that an AD Ezreal will benefit from will not be available to an AP Ezreal.

With these advantages and disadvantages in mind, whether you choose to go AP or AD on your Ezreal is entirely dependant on your play style.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jay, AP and AD are both viable, you have to consider your team comp though, if you're particularly wanting to play Ezreal though you can choose either.  While his auto attacks suffer somewhat if you go AP, you should only really be last hitting minions anyway in mid (or anywhere for that matter unless you're pushing), AP Ez can do his full combo for a heap of damage, personally I find AP to be suited to a more aggressive play style, you E in, then W > Q, most people back off, then you can follow up with an ult if you can get a kill.

Personally I don't find mana an issue, some people do but an early Tears will sort you out no problem.  Yes some AP champs can go for more damaging options early, so this can leave you feeling a little weak at some points, but Ez can be a slippery sod.  I tend to find playing as an AD carry harder, people want kills for carries, and with Ez these tend to rely on your lane partner setting it up, being *too* balsy will get you killed.  If you can get a Soraka with you in bot though (woo for unlimited mana!), you can pretty much completely zone the enemy.

IMO both AD and AP are perfectly viable, and both can be fun to play, and that's the best part :)